# Why call .self on cell class parameter when creating Table View Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Why can't I just have `TodayTableViewCell` instead of `TodayTableViewCell.self`?

```
 private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.registerClass(TodayTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

TableView's registerClass method expects an argument of type AnyObject.Type. You should pass a value of the cell's type.

From Apple's documentation:

> You can use the postfix self expression to access a type as a value.
>   For example, SomeClass.self returns SomeClass itself, not an instance
>   of SomeClass

You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455).

Comment: I see. That also explains why I was thrown an error when I did `TodayTableViewCell()` instead of `TodayTableViewCell.self` because the parameter wants a type and not an instance. Thank you!

Comment: For specificity's sake, It actually has an argument of AnyClass: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: which is a typealias of AnyObject.Type.